# Projection of point onto vector

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

[image]

Given vector x, when we project it onto vector u.. How is the distance from that point to origin equal to x'*u?

Comment: Please use MathJax.

Comment: Remember the identity $||x||||u||\cos\theta=x^Tu$. Then interpret the left-hand side.